# GVN algorithm in LLVM Infrastructure

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

Which algorithm is used for Global Value Numbering in LLVM? I see no paper or reference in GVN.cpp file. Does anybody know the details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It implements basic hash based RPO algorithm now but is being rewritten to implement the algorithm by Karthik Gargi (Sparse Algorithm for Predicated Global Value Numbering) according to the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/llvm-dev/MUCiFJVLDi4)